# Alias switch while data is being queried

Tags: elasticsearch

We are loading data into elasticsearch, the process is like this now:

1. Data is loaded daily around midnight
2. We assign alias to the data
3. Next day we start loading data into new index
4. Once data is loaded we switch alias to the new index

My question is - what happens if we run a query that started when alias pointed into first index and it continues when alias is switched. Will it continue querying the old index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, an alias switch [is atomic](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html), no need to worry about that.

When the query is received, first the indices behind the alias are resolved and the query is ran against those indices. So if you switch the alias while the query is still running, the query will continue running against the indices that were resolved and then the next query will run against the new indices pointed to by the alias.